# Free or open source IBM 3151 or aixterm emulators?

Tags: aix, terminal-emulator

Does anyone know of any free or open source terminal emulators that will emulate an IBM 3151 terminal or an HFT terminal (aixterm)?

We have some offshore contractors that need access to some of our systems that need a 3151 or hft emulation, but are having issues transferring licenses of Hummingbird HostExplorer to India.  For that matter, if we could save on US Hummingbird licenses it would be beneficial as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Should probably retag this to `aix-term`

Comment: I know this is an old post, but the reason some of us require proper IBM-3151 emulation over XTERM or anything else is that the emulation mode uses specific control sequences for many of the keys. For instance, the function keys use Line Turn Around character at the end of the byte sequence. Software written specifically for IBM 3151 emulation which utilize function keys will not work the same under other emulation modes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you'll find an open source or free emulator for this terminal type. While IBM has contributed to open source communities, they are also very interested in protecting their intellectual property. Hummingbird licenses are certainly expensive. We ran into issues with that when I worked for IBM!

That said, I never needed a specific terminal type in order to access AIX systems, as we used OpenSSH (comes with AIX 5L). Is there some reason why you can't provide SSH access to these systems to your contractors?